# java collection sort on the bases of another collection

Tags: java, collections

I have been asked this question in a interview:

```
Class Student{
  int rollno;
  String name;
  List<Mark> marks;
}

Class Mark{
  String subject;
  int mark;
}
```

How to get Student from Collection Student who has secured third highest marks?

Comment: How do you define "third highest marks"?

Comment: Well you could implement a looping system and a counter to count the number of students, then you will need to order them by descending order to get them in the correct order and then select the third highest

Comment: Suppose we are calculating the percentage/ average marks from List of Mark... But in that case we will have let say four Students with percentage 80%, five Students with 70%, three Students with 60%, two Students with 50%. Now we need all those Students with third highest percentage what is the best way to find out this?

Answer (score 0):

Since they are in a collection you can also call Collections.sort with a custom comparator like so:

```
   Collections.sort(studentList, new Comparator<Student>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(Student a, Student b) {
           double mark_a = Collections.max(a.marks);
           double mark_b = Collections.max(b.marks);
           return Double.compare(mark_a, mark_b);
       }
   });
```

Then you can simply return the third student. (you may need to change the calculation method for mark_a and mark_b depending on what "Highest Marks" means... They may want an average)

Comment: Suppose we are calculating the percentage/ average marks from List of Mark... But in that case we will have let say four Students with percentage 80%, five Students with 70%, three Students with 60%, two Students with 50%. Now we need all those Students with third highest percentage what is the best way to find out this?

Comment: Create a method that looks something like: `public double average(List<Marks> list){ double avg = 0; for(Mark m: list){ avg += m.mark;} return (avg / list.size()); }` then replace the lines `double mark_a = Collections.max(a.marks); and double mark_b = Collections.max(b.marks);` with `double mark_a = average(a.marks); and double mark_b = average(b.marks);`